# Greek numbering

Tags: numbering, greek

I wish to use numbering like 1\alpha, 1\beta,... in some subequations.
I know that this is obtainable by redefining the \theequation like the following 
(which gives lower-case Roman numerals, 1.i, 1.ii,...)

```
\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation{}.\roman{equation}}
\begin{align}
  a1 &= b1 \\
  a2 &= b2
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

The problem is I don't know the equivalent of \roman that will yield the Greek alphabet.

A related question (which might subsume the above) is: can someone complete the set of commands

```
\arabic, \alph, \Alph, \roman, \Roman, ...
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can create a Greek equivalent by taking the code of e.g. `\alph` from the file `latex.ltx` and modify it to get what you want. It also requires a slight modification to the `subequations` environment from [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\greek}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@greek\csname c@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\@greek}[1]{%
  $\ifcase#1\or\alpha\or\beta\or\gamma\or\delta\or\varepsilon
    \or\zeta\or\eta\or\theta\or\iota\or\kappa\or\lambda
    \or\mu\or\nu\or\xi\or o\or\pi\or\varrho\or\sigma
    \or\tau\or\upsilon\or\phi\or\chi\or\psi\or\omega
    \else\@ctrerr\fi$
}
\renewenvironment{subequations}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \protected@edef\theparentequation{\theequation}%
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation\greek{equation}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
      (a+b)^2 &= a^2+2ab+b^2 \\
      (a-b)^2 &= a^2-2ab+b^2 \\
      (a+b)(a-b) &= a^2-b^2
    \end{align}
  \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

You mentioned that you only want to modify some equations. The above introduced approach is a general modification. So you might have to do some adjustment on your own. At least you have Greek letters as enumeration symbols which also could be used at other places.

Comment: Great answer. Shame subequations needs so much redefinition.

Comment: Why redefine the `subequations` environment, when you can just do what the OP did in his post and `\renewcommand\theequation` inside the `\begin{subequations}...\end{subequations}` block?

Comment: @Willie: You are right. Another possibility would be to clone the `subequations` environment, do the necessary modification and give it a new name (e. g. `gsubequations`). The new environment could be used wherever wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I followed Willie's suggestion and dropped the code for modifying the `subeqations` environment. It all worked perfectly.

Comment: You need a `%` after `\else\@ctrerr\fi$` otherwise there will be a space after `\greek{counter}`

Answer (score 14):

Taking inspiration from [T.D.'s excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4058/greek-numbering/4063#4063), I wrote a small package to add extra counter output types. As well as greek, it defines binary, hexadecimal, and "First, Second, Third...".

- [`morenum.sty` on github](https://github.com/scmbradley/moreenum)
- [`moreenum` on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moreenum)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the \greeknumeral or \Greeknumeral  from the [babel](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/babel/) package. I am not sure how well they will play within a maths environment, but you can read the source for some inspiration.

Comment: Those are, I think, not quite the format the OP expects. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_numerals for what `\greeknumeral` outputs.

Comment: @Wong I am aware what a Greek Numeral (I speak, Greek!) Greek numerals (like their Roman counterparts) do not have a one to one representation with the alphabet. However, using the Babel package you can even have page-numbers with Greek numerals.

Answer (score 4):

There is no LaTeX2e equivalent for Greek letters. The only numbering command you're missing there is `\fnsymbol`, which is actually how you'll implement support for Greek letters yourself. `\fnsymbol` is (from source2e.pdf)

```
\def\fnsymbol#1{\expandafter\@fnsymbol\csname c@#1\endcsname}
```

and `\@fnsymbol` is

```
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or 
    *\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or\mathsection\or 
    \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger\or 
    \ddagger\ddagger 
  \else\@ctrerr\fi}}
```

So to define your own numbering scheme, just define a new macro along similar lines and insert the appropriate symbols.

There may be a package that does this already; another package along similar lines is `alphalph` which lets you display alphabetically numbers greater than 26: {`A`, …, `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `AA`, `AB`, …, `ZZ`, `AAA`, `AAB`, …, `FXSHRXW`}

Comment: Is FXSHRXW a random string of letters, or is it actually some limit on the size of the integers that TeX can handle, written in base 26? I somewhat doubt it because a string ending in W represents a even number (A = 0, Z = 25, W = 22), and limits on number sizes in computer science tend to be odd.

Comment: I just grabbed it from the alphalph docs; FXSHRXW is the max integer (corresponding to decimal 2147483647). I'm a bit rusty on my non-base-10 arithmetic, but for alphalph `A` = 1 and `W` = 23.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the command missing from my list. Your suggestion to modify the code above is basically what Thorsten did - but I saw his answer first!

Comment: No problem—his answer was better because he did the work of actually defining the new command!

Comment: [`moreenum.sty`](https://github.com/scmbradley/moreenum) uses `alphalph` to do exactly this.