# Setting arbitrary chapter values

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters

Friends, a colleague of mine showed me a book with a intriguing chapter structure:

[image: Content]

I was wondering how we could achieve something similar. I understand that this unusual numbering will break the counters, and I don't expect the chapter numbers to be set automatically, but I'd like to see how it could work even with a manual chapter numbering assignment.

As a minimum working example, I wrote a single code with some chapters added:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Before the beginning} % Chapter -1

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Much ado about nothing} % Chapter 0

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Small is beautiful} % Chapter 0.000000001

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{All is one} % Chapter 1

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Murdering irrationals} % Chapter \sqrt{2}

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Golden Phi} % Chapter \Phi

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The book looks interesting. Can you please tell me what is the name of the book?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\newcommand{\strangechapter}[1]{\renewcommand{\thechapter}{#1}\chapter}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\strangechapter{1}{X}
\strangechapter{$\pi$}{Y}
\end{document}
```

Use `\label` and `\ref` for the chapters with some care.

A definition in the preamble is preferable, since it forces the user to express the argument, without forgetting `\renewcommand` before `\chapter`. Moreover it provides a hook for enhancements of various type.

Don't forget to redefine `\thesection`, since "as we saw in section e.5" can be funny.

Comment: That's funny, I tried with `\label` and `\ref` and they worked perfecty! =)

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice solution for this question! BTW, I totally forgot about sections, glad you mentioned!

Answer (score 7):

The chapter counter is of course numeric but the display of it is controlled by the `\thechapter` macro. You could simply redefine it manually before every chapter. You could also map the chapter counter values to strings (see the link in Seamus answer), but in this case I don't think it would be worth the effort.

Example:

```
\clearpage% to flush out last chapter page with correct header and footer
\renewcommand{\thecapter}{0.000001}
\chapter{Small is beautiful}
```

Comment: I forgot that the chapter is just a macro that you could redefine. This is much simpler...

Comment: Pretty straightforward code, Martin! I had no idea I could do that.

Answer (score 3):

This is interesting, because the chapter number counter is an integer, so you couldn't just reset the counter to what you wanted before each chapter. I guess you could make a new enumeration scheme that just listed your chapter numbers in order like in this answer: [Greek numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4058/greek-numbering/4063#4063)

Comment: That's a very interesting approach, Seamus. I like the idea of iterating through an enumeration. =)