# How do I use Greek letters to enumerate a list?

Tags: numbering, lists, greek

[image: volvo3]

how do you change the numbering of a question so that the subparts are numbered with greek symbols like alpha and beta instead of the usual roman numerals?

Comment: It is hard to answer without some code we can play with. But take a look at the `enumitem` package, which provides the `label` key with which you can change the formatting. Though you'd have to define yourself a Greek counter formatter (e.g., here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4058/)

Comment: What have you tried, so far?

Comment: `\item[$\alpha$)]` is easier.

Comment: Egreg, will that code automatically give me second part which is beta like the way english letter numbering comes e.g a), b), c), d) etc ? remember the first option is alpha and the second is beta. and will the (2) at the far right automatically appear?

Answer (score 4):

The `babel` package defines localized Greek versions of `\alph` and `\Alph`.  In fact, it provides four variants of them.  One limitation is that all of them include the *kerala*, a prime symbol (ʹ) which is apparently correct for enumerating in Greek, but might not necessarily be what you want here.

If you want Greek letters without *kerala*, though, you could roll your own like the example in §8.1 of the `enumitem` mahual, or a more-readable version in expl3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex} % For \ifTUTeX

\pagestyle{empty} % Remove page numbers from this MWE

\ifTUTeX
  % Compiling with a Unicode engine.
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \babelprovide[import,alph=lower.modern,Alph=upper.modern]{greek}
  
  \babelfont{rm}
            [Ligatures={Common,TeX}, Language=Default]{CMU Serif}
\else
  % Compiling with an 8-bit engine.
  \usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\fi

\usepackage{enumitem}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\alphabeta}[1]{\foreignlanguage{greek}{\alph{#1}}}
\AddEnumerateCounter%
  {\alphabeta}%
  {\alphabeta}%
  {\foreignlanguage{greek}{\textomega}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\AlphaBeta}[1]{\foreignlanguage{greek}{\Alph{#1}}}
\AddEnumerateCounter%
  {\AlphaBeta}%
  {\AlphaBeta}%
  {\foreignlanguage{greek}{\textMu}}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\AlphaBeta*]
  \item foo
  \item bar
  \item baz
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alphabeta*]
    \item meep
    \item freep
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Greek enumeration sample]

You can italicize the labels like in your photo with something like `label=\textit{\alphabeta*}`.  You can also give your `label=` a format such as `\textgreek{\alph*}` or `\textgreek{\alph{enumi}}`.

Comment: +1 for the `\alphabeta` and `\AlphaBeta` numbering styles.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could add the way of how to get the greek labels without `kerala` since I didn't manage to do so. Thanks in advance!